# Cisco Mobility Express - supported authentication options

Tags: authentication, radius, aaa, tacacs, cisco-wireless

What are the supported authentication options for the ME APs? Do they support only login through local credentials or RADIUS/TACACS+ is also supported?

Comment: Management and authentication are two very different things. Are you really just asking about authentication?

Comment: Yes sorry, I mean authentication

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean host to network attachment, then it works much like any other Cisco wireless products using WPA2 Personal (Pre-Shared Key) or WPA2 Enterprise (802.1X using RADIUS).

If you mean logging into the controller, it is very much like any other Cisco device, and you can use AAA with RADIUS or TACACS+.

Cisco maintains a full library of documentation for its products, including things like, [*Cisco Mobility Express Deployment Guide*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/technotes/8-2/b_Mobility_Express_Deployment_guide.html).

Comment: I got a bit confused because of information in the Feature Matrix at this page - https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/technotes/8-7/b_feature_matrix_for_802_11ac_wave2_access_points.html . It says "Local Auth w/External RADIUS Server" is not supported in Mobility Express mode however i'm not sure if they mean logging to the controller or logging hosts to the networks.

Comment: You need to look at the CLI. For example, "_To configure settings for a RADIUS authentication server for the Cisco wireless LAN controller, use the `config radius auth` command._"